# How to get the Build url of the triggered job in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
                script {
                     def job = build job: '<job>'
                           if (job.getResult().equals('FAILURE')) {
                           def jobName = '<job>'
                           def date = new Date().format('dd/MM/yyyy')
                                        echo "Build Result: " + job.getResult()
                                        slackSend color: "danger", message: "${jobName} failed on " + date + "\n Build URL - ${absoluteUrl}"
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        echo "Build Result: " + job.getResult()
                                    }
                        }
```

How to get the build url for ''.
By using 'JOB_URL' I get the url of the Parent Job.
And 'absoluteUrl' throws ' `No such property: absoluteUrl for class: groovy.lang.Binding`' error.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`absoluteUrl` is not defined. `job.getAbsoluteUrl()` would give you the URL.
See [documentation](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html)